# Which APIs are accessible through Google API Client Library for PHP?

Tags: php, google-maps, google-api, google-places-api, google-api-php-client

I wanted to use [it](https://packagist.org/packages/google/apiclient) to access Google Places API Web Service, but I can't find corresponding class.

The documentation says:

> Google APIs give you programmatic access to Google Maps, Google Drive, YouTube, and many other Google products.

Am I doing it wrong? What are the criteria for including APIs in the library?

Comment: Don't forget to leave a comment when downvoting ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP Client Library does not include a class for Google Places; Nevertheless, it allows you to make HTTP Requests Directly. Since Google Places API is also RESTful (example https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) then you can use the PHP client library to make HTTP requests directly. Please read the documentation here https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client#making-http-requests-directly. That should get you started. I hope this helps!

Comment: And as for criterion? Is it going to be added sometime in the future?

Comment: That is something I can't answer. I'm sorry I can't help you there. If I find something out, I will update this thread.